# Why do the averages of $\sin (p+\cos p )$ approach a positive limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, trigonometric-series

$$S_1 = \sum_{k=1}^n (\sin \left[~ p(k) + \cos p(k)~ \right])$$

I wonder why this appears to give $$\frac{1}{n}S_2\sim 1/2 $$

Thanks for any insights or references.

Edited in light of comments--some code and a picture of $S_2.$

$S_2$= Table[Sum[Sin[ Prime[i] + Cos[ Prime[i]]], {i, 1, j}], {j, 1, 300}]]

[image: partial sums over primes]

---

This appears to be a pattern for all positive integers, not something special about primes. The average of $\sin(k+\cos k)$ over $1\le k\le n$ appears to converge to  $\approx 0.44$. Here is a list plot of these averages for $ 200\le n\le 2000$:

[image: averages over all positive integers]

Comment: So, you have $\sin(p(k)+\cos(p(k)))$, with cosine inside of the sine? For **that** sequence I see the same pattern (which is interesting), but this is not the formula you had in the question.

Comment: @WeaponofChoice: Yes...I am going to delete this and go to sleep :)...thanks. Maybe I will repost the possibly interesting series later. Thanks.

Comment: Also, once you put cosine inside of sine, the first summation produces the same result: average about $0.44$. So, this is something about $\sin(n+\cos n)$ for integer $n$, nothing special about primes.

Comment: Hey! Why delete, if this is an interesting pattern? Just change the formulas to reflect what you actually observed.

Comment: I added a plot of averages made in Sage; I think it looks very neat.

Comment: @WeaponofChoice: Very nice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sequence converges to
$$J_1(1) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(t+\cos t) \, \mathrm{d} t \approx 0.440051. $$
The series expansion of the Bessel function gives an alternative expression for this constant:
$$J_1(1) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(m+1)!2^{2m+1}}.$$
This expression easily implies that $J_1(1)$ is irrational.

Consider first the simpler sequence
$$ A_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \sin(i+\cos i). $$
The function $f(t) = \sin(t+\cos t)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. The [equidistribution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) implies that $i \pmod{2\pi}$ is asymptotically equidistributed in $[0,2\pi)$, and so
$$ A_n \to \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(t+\cos t) \, \mathrm{d} t. $$

Next, your prime sequence
$$ B_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \sin(p_i+\cos p_i), $$
where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime. A [deep theorem of Vinogradov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Examples) implies that $p_i \pmod{2\pi}$ is asymptotically equidistributed in $[0,2\pi)$, and we get the same result.

Comment: +1 for very nice and neat solution. More effort can prove things such as $\sum_p \frac{\sin p}p$ converges.